# Adding data to csv file without touching previous data in the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have a csv file named "data.csv":

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
10       20       30       40
12       23       78       98
23       67       101      123
24       70       104      130
25       73       105      131
```

Then I am running:

```
df_out = df.diff()
df_out = df_out.dropna()
df_out.to_csv('newdata.csv', index=False)
```

This makes it so the rows are subtracted from one another and the result
gets printed into a new csv file:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  
2        3        48       58      
11       44       23       25      
1        3        3        7
1        3        1        1
```

Values are constantly being added in "data.csv" file, which mean the "newdata.csv" is constantly being updated with the difference.

**Problem**: Everytime I run the code, it first starts subtracting from row 1 of the "data.csv" file but I only want it to find the difference for the new values without touching the older data in "newdata.csv"

Is that something that is possible within pandas?

Comment: there's something fishy when you say "Values are constantly being added" and then "it first starts subtracting from row 1" please show or explain more of what you mean as there's not enough code here to see what is going wrong.

Comment: @Jab I am parsing a json file which is outputs network packet data, which then gets added to a csv file names "data.csv", I am not asking anyone to correct certain code, just asking for a function within pandas which would allow me to update only future data in csv file without touching data that was already there at the time of execution of code

Comment: You could set the mode in `to_csv` to `'a'` for append. It defaults to `'w'` for write.

Comment: @Jab that's weird, i was trying the append before but it was giving me an error cause Column names were being printed onto my csv file. So i figured out that apparently i forgot i put "QUOTE_ALL" and that was reprinting column names i ran the code. Append worked for this. thanks

Comment: As a comment on your methodology, ***streaming data*** or [***message-queues***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/message-queue) are probably more suitable design patterns if you only want to perform action on new chunks of data. Suggest you look into them.